# How to handle backspace in VSCode terminal renderer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension which requires me to use VSCode's `TerminalRenderer` API. My requirement is to take user input directly from the terminal and perform actions based on that.

I followed the [vscode-extension-samples terminal example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/terminal-sample). However, I noticed that when the user is trying to use the backspace / del key, the characters are not deleted. There is a related issue [logged](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52951) in VSCode's GitHub repo but it is closed with *as designed*.

Any help in solving the issue is appreciated.